# Angular Component Lifecicle not Triggered inside ViewContainerRef.createComponent + OnPush

Tags: angular

When you dynamically create a component using the `ViewContainerRef.createComponent` method, if the Child Component has `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` the Child Component content lifecycle is not triggered.

```
  private attachChildComponent = (childComponent: ComponentType<any>, container: ViewContainerRef) => {
      const componentFactory = this.factor.resolveComponentFactory(childComponent);
      const childComponentRef = container.createComponent(componentFactory);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

When we use `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` we need to trigger the change detection manually, using the `ComponentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`

```
const childComponentRef = this.childContainer.createComponent(componentFactory);
childComponentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); // force OnPush to detect
```